# php string to int

Tags: php, string, int

```
$a = '88';
$b = '88 8888';

echo (int)$a;
echo (int)$b;
```

as expected, both produce 88. Anyone know if there's a string to int function that will work for $b's value and produce 888888? I've googled around a bit with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: What int value are you expecting for $b? 888888?

Comment: PHP does not follow the `ISO standard 31-0` when it casts a string to integer. PHP has it's own specification, outlined here: [String conversion to numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can remove the spaces before casting to `int`:

```
(int)str_replace(' ', '', $b);
```

Also, if you want to strip other commonly used digit delimiters (such as `,`), you can give the function an array (beware though -- in some countries, like mine for example, the comma is used for fraction notation):

```
(int)str_replace(array(' ', ','), '', $b);
```

Comment: or if you want to remove all non numeric characters (int)preg_replace('#[^0-9]+#', '', $b);

Comment: beware of (int), the maximum supported value is 2147483647, so if you have (int)2222222222 it will return 2147483647

Answer (score 12):

If you want to leave only numbers - use preg_replace like: (int)preg_replace("/[^\d]+/","",$b).

Answer (score 1):

What do you even want the result to be? 888888? If so, just remove the spaces with `str_replace`, then convert.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the whitespace characters, and then convert it(using the intval function or by regular typecasting)

```
intval(str_replace(" ", "", $b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` to remove the spaces first ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str_replace` when you declare your variable $b like that :

```
$b = str_replace(" ", "", '88 8888');
echo (int)$b;
```

Or the most beautiful solution is to use intval :

```
$b = intval(str_replace(" ", "", '88 8888');
echo $b;
```

If your value '88 888' is from an other variable, just replace the '88 888' by the variable who contains your String.